# Failed to get broadcast_5_piece0 of broadcast5

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

Getting the error "`Failed to get broadcast_5_piece0 of broadcast5`" while running spark application with 2 worker instances.
I have also set `spark.cleaner.ttl`, after that also I am getting the same error. 
can anyone please help?

Full stack Trace Can be found here :

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_5_piece0 of broadcast_5
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1212)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_5_piece0 of broadcast_5
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1205)
    ... 11 more
```

Adding Code............

```
public class Insert_into_cassandra implements Serializable {
    static List<String> signal_name_pass=new ArrayList<String>();
    static int count=4;
    static SparkConf conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("Insert_into_cassandra").setMaster("local").set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");
    static JavaSparkContext jspc=new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    static SparkContextJavaFunctions functions=CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(jspc);
     static Insert_into_cassandra iic=new Insert_into_cassandra();
     static int  value_in_db=0;
public static  void main(String gg[])
{


JavaRDD<String> rbmfile=jspc.textFile("/home/amd/Desktop/prac");


JavaPairRDD<String, Parse_Object> signal_name=rbmfile.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Parse_Object>() {


    public Tuple2<String, Parse_Object> call(String x) throws Exception {

        return new Tuple2<String, Parse_Object>(x.split("  ")[0], new Parse_Object(x.split("  ")[1],x.split("  ")[2],x.split("  ")[3]));
    }
});



JavaRDD<CassandraRow> signal_name_cassandra=functions.cassandraTable("tutorialspoint", "stuff_id_2");



JavaRDD<CassandraRow> sort=signal_name_cassandra.sortBy(new Function<CassandraRow, String >() {


    public String call(CassandraRow x) throws Exception {

        return x.getString(0);
    }
}, false, 1).coalesce(1);


value_in_db=Integer.parseInt(sort.first().getString(0));


JavaPairRDD<String, String> take_signal_name=signal_name_cassandra.mapToPair(new PairFunction<CassandraRow, String, String>() {

    public Tuple2<String, String> call(CassandraRow x) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return new Tuple2<String, String>(x.getString(1),x.getString(0));
    }
});



/*JavaPairRDD<String, String> getting_max_id=signal_name_cassandra.mapToPair(new PairFunction<CassandraRow, String, String>() {

    @Override
    public Tuple2<String, String> call(CassandraRow x) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return new Tuple2<String, String>(x.getString(0),x.getString(1));
    }
});*/


 JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<Optional<String>, Parse_Object>> join=take_signal_name.rightOuterJoin(signal_name);



JavaPairRDD<String, String> getting_id=join.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String,Tuple2<Optional<String>,Parse_Object>>, String, String>() {

    public Tuple2<String, String> call(
            Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Optional<String>, Parse_Object>> x)
            throws Exception {

        if(x._2()._1().isPresent())
        {
            System.out.println("if----"+x._1());
            return new Tuple2<String, String>(x._1().toString(), x._2()._1().toString());

        }

        else
        {
            signal_name_pass.add(x._1());

        }
    return null;

    }


}).filter(new Function<Tuple2<String,String>, Boolean>() {


    public Boolean call(Tuple2<String, String> x) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return x!=null;
    }
});
getting_id.saveAsTextFile("/home/amd/Desktop/smal/get13");
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting Spark Cleaner TTL is almost always the wrong thing to do in modern versions of spark. This could be leading to premature removal of important cached data. It's much safer to let the built in Context Cleaner do it's work.

If turning off the TTL doesn't fix things you'll need to provide more relevant details like:

1. Any suspicious logs on the executors?
2. Full stack trace of the
   exception?
3. Example of the Code you are running?

Comment: I want to ask one think, I am not using Broadcast Variable, so what Broadcast Variable Spark is using?

Comment: 1) Nothing suspcious logs on executors. 3) II am inserting two rows in the cassandra, after fiiltering it. Let me know if you want anything more.

Comment: Please add some code so that we can see whats the problem is !